# Pug file compilation returns an error of mixins.pug is not found

Tags: html, gruntjs, pug

I am new to pug/jade. I have 3 pug template files named "layout.pug", "home.pug" and "mixins.pug".
The layout.pug contains following code:

```
html
  include mixins
  body
    include home
```

The code in this home.pug file:

```
body
  div.main
    +popup('Hello', 'Hello World')
```

The pug file 'mixins.pug' contains mixins. I have added the mixin popup() to this file.
The code in this file:

```
mixin popup(title, description)
 div.pop-up-body
   h2 #{title}
   p #{description}
```

But when I compile my pug files using `grunt pug` command, I got an error
"pug_mixins.popup is not a function".

If you know the reason, kindly help me.

Comment: it seems like you don't need to use `#{}` inside a mixin declaration you can just write your variable as she is `h2 title`

Comment: Hi, I tried with this. But it displays only the word "title" on the browser, not the value of the variable title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer to this question.

**The reason of the error:**
   I had included the `mixins.pug` in the `layout.pug` file. But the 
   mixin `popup(title, description)` is called from the `home.pug` file.
   So the mixin is not available in the `home.pug` file. 
   (The `home.pug` is also included in `layout.pug` file. So I included the `mixins.pug` only in the `layout.pug` file).

**Solution:**
   I removed the code `include mixins` from `layout.pug` file and added it
   to the `home.pug` file.

**Code:**
 layout.pug file

```
html
   body
      include home
```

home.pug file

```
include mixins
div.main
   +popup('Hello', 'Hello World')
```

mixins.pug file

```
mixin popup(title, description)
   div.pop-up-body
       h2 #{title}
       p #{description}
```